# Windows Scripts for excuting query

Tags: mysql, scripting

I am usign an application which can run scripts like wsh, vbs, bat. Is also possible to "pass" parameters to the scripts. I wanted to excute `INSERT` query into Mysql database, how I can achive it? The application runs something like that:

`myscript NameTable, string1, string2, string3`

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

[Link](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/tip.php?id=808)

> To run a batch script from the
>   operating system command line, type
>   something like this from the command
>   prompt:
>
> mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "set
>   @1:='some value'; source run.sql;"
>
> This can be expanded as you like.
>   Alternatively, you can put everything
>   in run.sql.
>
> This needs only:
>
> (i) the mysql program in the current
>   folder, or in the path
>
> (ii) run.sql in the current folder
>
> Pass params to a MySQL client script
>   from a shell script:
>
> echo SELECT @foo > /tmp/myscript.sql 
>   echo SET @foo := 'bar'; >
>   /tmp/setvar.sql  echo SOURCE
>   /tmp/setvar.sql; SOURCE
>   /tmp/myscript.sql; > /tmp/turnkey.sql 
>   mysql -uUSR -pPWD < /tmp/turnkey.sql 
>   rm /tmp/setvar.sql /tmp/turnkey.sql
>
> Under Windows, the MySQL client script
>   interface can be finicky. Substitute
>   your MySQL username & password for USR
>   and PWD, then this example works:
>
> if not exist c:\tmp md c:\tmp  echo
>   show tables from test >
>   c:\tmp\test.sql  "c:\program
>   files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   6.0\bin\mysql.exe " -uUSR -pPWD -e "source c:\tmp\test.sql"
>
> For example to parameterise Load Data
>   Infile:
>
> REM Batch file mysqlLDI.BAT to
>   parameterise MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE
>   command:  REM Call with %1 = input
>   filename, %2 = db.table  echo LOAD
>   DATA INFILE '%1' INTO TABLE %2 LINES
>   TERMINATED BY "\r\n" > \tmp\doit.sql 
>   mysql -uUSR -pPWD < /tmp/doit.sql